# How to dynamically change the content of an item in a ListView/RecyclerListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

In my application the user can add products and when they do, they are back to the products list which is a RecyclerView with CardView items.

The specification says that if I am uploading 7 images or products, a header should appear above the RecyclerView and display the progress, like "Uploading 1 of 7 items", "Uploading 2 of 7 items" and so on so forth. Then it should disappear and the listview should go back to normal.

I tried attaching a header view (and succeeded) to the RecyclerView, and I was able to update its contents and to hide it, but whenever I hide it, an empty space remains there and I cant make the listview go back up to its original position, I tried lots of things I even make it null, and rebuild it a new, and set the adapter anew... Nothing helps.

So I decided to introduce two types of items for the RecyclerView.Adapter - TYPE_HEADER and TYPE_PRODUCT
Now I am implementing this, but it occurred to me that I dont know how to dynamically update the TextView inside the item of TYPE_HEADER (I am using a handler that receives messages from the uploader service, but I dont know how to reach the TYPE_HEADER item in the RecyclerView.Adapter in order to change its TextView dynamically.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this **inside** the ListView/RecyclerView? The header is the first item in the list. If you have scrolled the list, this header won't be visible. Wouldn't it be simpler to have a `RelativeLayout` with this "header" as the top item and then simply show/hide it depending on the progress? Or am I understanding your requirements wrong?

Comment: I think I've tried that one (last time I worked on this was two months ago) but I am not sure. I had completely forgotten about that idea, I will give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using **RecycleView** and I needed a header which can scroll up with listview. I tried every possible solutions which can create smooth effect and no extra space when you scroll up.

**WORKING SOLUTION**

I made the header as a part of the listview. So, You can do the same thing, When you need the header, make it an item at **position 0** in list view and from position 1 your actual listview starts.

When you don't need it, you can just remove item at Position 0.

This will not give you any problems like Extra space or other things.

Also, you can update Textview inside it in your bindView() in RecycleAdapter.

**EDITED**

For an Example, You have a broadcast receiver(Or, it can be a button click or any other event) which says now its time to update the TextView inside the HeaderView.

In that Receiver, You can actually set a global flag to true, notifyDataSetChanged() and then in your RecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder, depending on your global flag's value, you can update the TextView.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that part -> Also, you can update Textview inside it in your bindView() in RecycleAdapter.

Comment: This won't work if the list is already scrolled so that the first visible position is not 0. If you absolutely have to do it this way, you will also need to scroll the list to the top. This may or may not be a horrible UX but that's up to you to decide. Personally I'd never do it this way. A `RelativeLayout` with a view flagged with `layout_above="@+id/listview"` is what I'd choose and then change the visibility when required. This way, the list doesn't have to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you only ever need one view of type HEADER, you can hang onto it in the Adapter:

```
private HeaderViewHolder headerView;

public HeaderViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder()
{
    return headerView;
}

@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        if(headerView == null)
        {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            headerView = new HeaderViewHolder(view);
        }

        return headerView;
    }
    else
    {
        //Inflate view normally...
    }
}
```

You can then just ignore the header view in `onBindViewHolder`. Instead, have the activity get the HeaderView directly from the adapter

Then your activity can get the `HeaderViewHolder` directly from the adapter, and update it on demand.